# Passing command line arguments to running Electron app without packaging

Tags: electron

I'm trying to pass arguments into an already-running Electron app started via the command line (`electron .`).

The application is configured to allow only a single instance using `app.makeSingleInstance`. Ideally the app will receive the args then process them instead of launching a new instance.

I can easily pass arguments into my app like this:

```
electron . --arg1 --arg2
```

However I am not sure how to pass them into an already-running Electron instance.

I know I can package the app into an .exe and test it that way, however having to package each time I want to test is cumbersome.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I didn't properly implement `app.makeSingleInstance`.

According to the [documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.36.0/api/app/#appmakesingleinstancecallback), you must handle how the app reacts when an additional instance is started, in this case quitting the new instance after parameters are passed to the running one.

As for testing this, simply opening a second command window works.

On the first command window, I start the app:

```
electron . arg1 arg2
```

And it processes the two args.

In a second command window:

```
electron . arg3 arg4
```

And the third and fourth arguments are processed by the first app.